# Qt slot takes const & QString, signal takes just QString

Tags: qt, qt-signals

I inherited Qt code in which the signals typically are declared with the just the types: E.g.

```
class One : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
    gotEvent(QString message);
}
```

```
class Two : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
slots:
    handleEvent(QString const &message);
}
```

```
QObject::connect(one_instance, &One::gotEvent, two_instance, &Two::handleEvent);
```

When I call `emit gotEvent(string);` from the One class (assuming one_instance and two_instance are in the same thread), does the string get copied, or is it  passed by reference to handleEvent()?

In other words, does the const-ness of the string depend on the signal declaration, or only the slot declaration? I'm assuming the way it's declared in the signal doesn't make any difference, because the signal isn't a defined function, but I'd like to know for sure.

Comment: They are both real functions. Look at the generated moc code for details. So, a shallow copy will be made on the signal side of the machinery.